# Splitting One Big WordPress Site into Multiple Small Sites

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a very big WordPress site and I am facing speed issue and server resources issues. Specially numbers of MySQL records are so high. So, I want to split the big WordPress site into multiple small sites.

I have URL structure like this

1. http://siteurl.com/this-is-first-post.html (category1)
2. http://siteurl.com/this-is-second-post.html (category2)
3. http://siteurl.com/this-is-third-post.html (category1 and category2)

I want to separate the WordPress according to category, I am thinking about two solutions

1. Either I create two DBs for each categories, e.g. `db_cat1` and `db_cat2` and I divide the data using some logic.
2. Or I create subdomains and install different WP instances like this:

   - http://category1.siteurl.com/this-is-first-post.html
   - http://category2.siteurl.com/this-is-second-post.html

My questions are:

1. If I try the first logic, then how can I divide the databases into different categories db?
2. If I try second logic, then how can I manage the URL structure and keep SEO juice there? How can I divide the common tags and categories?
3. How I will manage resources such as image etc after splitting the WordPress?
4. Is there any better way to do this job?

I don't want change the server or work on server because I already tried different types of server and all servers have the MySQL resources issues. I prefer second logic because it is easy to handle.

Comment: Wordpress admin questions: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I presume you have also already tried Page Caching plugins and moving other resources eg images etc to cloud services like Amazon S3?

Comment: yes i am using wp super cache plugin and i am on digital ocean server, the main issue is with memory/cpu, server hangs after every few days.